# find lowest value by using item name and change low value background color in html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I've list of items and price in html table. i need to find low price in the item and change the background color of the cell in the `html table`.

first Lowest value `background-color` is "Bue".

second lowest value `background-color` is "green".

third lowest value `background-color` is "orange".

**My Table is:**

Item-Name         Price

A                        12

A                        18

A                        9

A                        13

B                        5

B                        8

B                        12

**Expected Result:**

Item-Name         Price

### A                 12

A                        18

## A                9

#### A                   13

## B               5

### B                 8

#### B                   12

In this Expected result table I've given  `<h1>` tag for first lowest value, `<h2>` for second lowest value and `' for third lowest value.

I don't know how to change background color in this question so that I've given `Header tags`

Please help me how to find low values using `jquery`.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide some code so we can see your selectors. Thanks

Comment: take my jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/45w5vfne/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/gokrrucr/6/`
```

please Check this fiddle to get ur Ans..this will work dyamically

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

var valArr = [];

$('tbody tr td:nth-child(0)').each(function () {
  valArr.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

valArr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

$('tbody tr td:nth-child(0)').each(function () {
  if(parseInt($(this).text()) == valArr[0]){
     //Color Lowest Row
  }else if(parseInt($(this).text()) == valArr[1]){
     //Color Second Lowest Row By getting Parents
  }else if(parseInt($(this).text()) == valArr[2]){
    //Color Third Lowest Row By getting Parents
  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: It Will Work for You

Comment: Please Check above fiddle

Comment: item A value 9 is lowest value there it's showing orange color it should show blue color

Comment: 9 is lowest value in item A and 5 is lowest value in item B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117576/discussion-between-siddaramesh-and-adi).

Comment: thanks https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/gokrrucr/2/  this is ok for two items if I've more than 50 different  items. it will not work

Comment: Then you Just need to make it dynamic

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it

Comment: I got solution thanks for your support. could you please copy your jfiddle code to stack overflow answer section.